# List only ActiveRecord subclass methods

Tags: ruby, activerecord, metaprogramming

Given the following ActiveRecord model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games
  def name
    "Joe"
  end

  def city
     "Chicago"
  end
end
```

I'd like to retrieve a list of the methods I added directly to the User class (and not those added by extending ActiveRecord and/or adding associations). Example output:

```
["name","city"]
```

Calling User.instance_methods(false) returns method added by ActiveRecord:

```
["validate_associated_records_for_games", "games", "game_ids", "games=", "game_ids=", "after_create_or_update_associated_records_for_games", "before_save_associated_records_for_games"]
```

Along with any model attributes from database columns. I'd like to exclude those and just get the custom methods on the subclass.

My purpose is method tracing: I'd like to trace my custom methods while excluding those added by ActiveRecord.

Any ideas?

Comment: what version of rails are you using?

Comment: I'm testing w/Rails 2.2.2, but I'm open to solutions for more recent versions.

Comment: In rails 3.2 the attribute accessors, association accessors and maybe the validations stuff are defined in methods that are included into your model for you, which makes what you're trying to do easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `method_added` hook which adds method names to a list, and monkey patch Active Record so that methods added by AR are not added to that list.

If you don't want to crack AR open and start poking around, you could also define a "class macro" which defines a method *and* adds it to the list. For your own custom methods, use the class macro rather than `def`.

If you're not familiar with what I'm referring to as a "class macro", it's simply a method like this:

```
class Class
  def mydef(name,&block)
    (@methods || []) << name
    define_method(name,&block)
  end
end
```

Using something like `mydef` to define methods rather than `def` is definitely ugly, but it would solve the problem without requiring any monkey-patching.

Comment: To clarify, a "class macro" is an instance method on `Class` which you can call from within a `class` block to define methods, etc. `attr_accessor` is another example.

Comment: What about arguments for methods?

Comment: If the block passed to `define_method` takes arguments, the generated method will also take arguments.

Comment: Yes - this would work. Like you said, I'd need to change my method definitions across models. I like this direction though: I've overridden ActiveRecord::Base's `extend` method to add a `method_added` call to subclasses. It checks to see if the first caller's file name matches the subclass. If so, it adds the method name to an Array. This isn't perfect, but it does grab all of the methods defined in the model file.

Comment: Nice idea, I like it! If this answer helped you solve your problem, an upvote+accept would be appreciated. If you can share code which might be useful to future readers, you can edit this post to add it (I'll approve the edit).

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'll post my code when I've cleaned it up a bit (still testing things out).

Answer (score 1):

```
User.instance_methods - ActiveRecord::Base.instance_methods #=> [:name,:city]
```

UPDATE:

the order of these methods are significant

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.my_own_methods
    self.instance_methods - @@im
  end
  has_many :games
  @@im = self.instance_methods
  def name
    "Joe"
  end
  def city
    "Chicago"
  end
end

User.my_own_methods #=> [:name, :city]
```

This one tested and it works

Comment: This doesn't work, because the methods automatically generated by AR (such as those for DB columns) will not be in `ActiveRecord::Base.instance_methods`.

Comment: Yeah - this returns methods that ActiveRecord adds to the User class. For example, you'll see output like `:games=`, which I don't want, but is included because of the `has many :games` association.

Comment: Yes - this works and it's simple. Downside is that implementing it across all ActiveRecord models wouldn't be DRY and the method ordering would need to be documented.